# Trigger para auto-insertar valores en una tabla

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Soy nuevo en la proyección de bases de datos.

Tengo 3 tablas:

**users:**

```
+--------+--------+---------+----------+--------+
| userid |  name  | surname | password | admin  |
+--------+--------+---------+----------+--------+
| value1 | value2 | value3  | value4   | value5 |
+--------+--------+---------+----------+--------+
```

**users_attributes:**

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|   id   |  name  |  type  |  
+--------+--------+--------+
| value1 | value2 | value3 |  
+--------+--------+--------+
```

**users_attributes_values(con llave foranea userid e attributeid):**

```
+--------+-------------+----------------+
| userid | attributeid | attributevalue |
+--------+-------------+----------------+
| value1 | value2      | value3         |
+--------+-------------+----------------+
```

La relacion de los users con los attributes es **uno a muchos**, ejemplo: 
Si hay 5 users, y creo 3 attributes:

1. **Edad**:20 con tipo integer
2. **Fecha de nacimiento**: 23/12/1992 con tipo date
3. **Religion**: Musulmana con tipo string

entonces cada uno de los 5 tendrá estos 3 attributes.

Cuando viene insertado un nuevo attribute en la tabla **users_attributes**, quiero que en la tabla **users_attributes_values** vengan insertados automaticamente los referimientos a aquel attribute para cada user presente.
Creo/Inserto 2 attributes:

```
INSERT INTO users_attributes(
            id, name, type)
    VALUES ('1', 'Peso', 'Int');

INSERT INTO users_attributes(
            id, name, type)
    VALUES ('2', 'Estatura', 'Int');
```

al insertarlos el trigger insertara en **users_attributes_value** el id de los user presentes y el id de los attributos apenas creados, Ejemplo, hay 3 user presentes:

```
+--------+-------------+----------------+
| userid | attributeid | attributevalue |
+--------+-------------+----------------+
|      1 |           1 |                |
|      1 |           2 |                |
|      2 |           1 |                |
|      2 |           2 |                |
|      3 |           1 |                |
|      3 |           2 |                |
|        |             |                |
+--------+-------------+----------------+
```

Este es el resultado esperado después de crear nuevos attributes, como podría obtener este resultado usando triggers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un trigger *after insert*, que básicamente haga un `insert` en la tabla `users_attributes_values` para cada usuario que exista en la tabla `users` y colocando el nuevo *atributo* en el campo correspondiente.

En la línea de:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_users_attributes_values() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        --
        -- para cada nueva fila insertada en users_attributes crea las filas
        -- correspondientes en users_attributes_values para todos los 
        -- users existentes en la base de datos
        --
        IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            insert into users_attributes_values (userid, attributeid)
            select userid, NEW.id
              from users;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER users_attributes_create_users_attributes_values
AFTER INSERT ON users_attributes
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_users_attributes_values();
```

Comment: Al crear la función recibo este mensaje: Query returned successfully with no result in 331 ms. La función no se crea.

Comment: Bueno, he escrito el código aquí mismo. La idea no es que hagas copy/paste sino que lo estudies, lo comprendas y lo adaptes a tus necesidades. No tengo un motor de DB a mano ni tu estructura de tablas para validarlo por mi mismo. Estás seguro que no te da ningún error y aún así no se crea la función?

Comment: Claro, el código lo estudie, y vi que no había necesidad de cambiarlo.

Comment: Nada, la función si se creo, solo que no podía visualizarla, no se por que, de todos modos funciona, gracias por tu respuesta!